# another way of solving $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{e})^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{e}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

My attempt:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{ln(1+x)}{x}}}{e}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(e^{\frac{ln(1+x)}{x}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(e^{\frac{ln(1+x)-x}{x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\cdot \frac{ln(1+x)-x}{x}}$$

After I applied L'Hospital twice I got $e^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$
My question:there is another way to approach this exercise?Another easier or faster method ?

Answer (score 2):

It's much better, in my opinion, to get rid of the exponential, using the fact that if $\lim_{x\to a}\log f(x)=l$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=e^l$ (with obvious extensions if $l=\pm\infty$).

Then you need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\bigl(1+x)^{1/x}\bigr)-1}{x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-x^2/2+o(x^2)-x}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Taylor series of $\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$,

We have

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\frac{x^2}2-x}{x^2}=-\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\bigg(\frac{{(1+x)}^{1/x}}{e}\bigg)^{1/x}$

$\Rightarrow ln\big(f(x)\big)=\frac{1}{x}\bigg(\frac{1}{x}ln(1+x)-ln(e)\bigg)$

$\Rightarrow ln\big(f(x)\big)=\frac{1}{x}\bigg(\frac{1}{x}(\frac{x}{1}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots)-1\bigg)$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0}ln\big(f(x)\big)=ln\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$

$\Rightarrow e^{ln\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

Comment: Note that there are only two important ideas you need here. First idea: $\lim_{x \to x_0}ln\big(f(x)\big)=ln\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$  as long as $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) \gt 0$. Second idea: $ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$.